# How to jump out from string value when using Resharper

Tags: keyboard, resharper, resharper-6.0

I want to jump out from quotes. When I was not using ReSharper 'Tap' key helped to jump out from double quotes, but it is not working when using ReSharper.
Of course I do not want to use right arrow key.

Help please.

[image: reharper]

Comment: @Snowbear I think he meant `Tab`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to jump out of the method arguments altogether, use Ctrl+Shift+Enter (Complete Statement).
If your intention is to quit the current string value to start entering the next argument, then I'm not sure anything apart from the right arrow or Ctrl + right arrow will work.
What's the 'Tap' key btw?

Comment: tap key works the same as Ctrl + right arrow key. That is what I was looking for. ctrl+shift+enter seems useful, but it does not do anything in my vs

Comment: Weird: the shortcut for Complete Statement is the same between both keymaps. Try going to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard and see if ReSharper.ReSharper_CompleteStatement is assigned this shortcut (it could possibly be used by another command related or not related to ReSharper.) Btw here's an old yet useful post on using Complete Statement in different scenarios: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2008/05/resharper-in-detail-complete-statement-scenarios/

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> which is 'Expand selection'. Pressing it around three times will select the entire string literal. Then you can press <kbd>→</kbd> to go to the right side of selection.

I'm not sure whether there is such a command in Resharper, but if you're saying that this command there was in VS before Resharper then you can find this command in `Options->Environment->Keyboard`